# UITableViewCell lazy instantiation cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, uitableview, lazy-initialization

I have a UITableView called **UserProductViewController** and this table view used for two purpose "*create and edit*" some data. When user click "edit button" open this **UserProductViewController** edit mode and populate some data within cell from another method. I don't want to store all server-side values in property instead I was use Lazy instantiation cell. This approach sometimes makes trouble. To be clear here is my code this approach correct or not ? Could you please guide me correct way to do this?

**Implementation Interface**

```
@interface UserProductViewController() 
@property(strong, nonatomic) MyCustomTableViewCell *myCustomCell;
@end

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...

    if(indexPath.row == 2) return self.myCustomCell;

    ...
}

- (MyCustomTableViewCell *)myCustomCell {
    if(!_myCustomCell) {
        _myCustomCell = [self.tabView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomIdentifier" forIndexPath:[self customIndexPath]];
    }

    return _myCustomCell;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)customIndexPath {
    // 2 correspond to cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath value.   
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
}
```

**Server side method I'm using that cell as a property like this:**

```
- (void) getUserValues {

        ....
        // getting server-side result
       //  completion block
      self.myCustomCell.titleLabel = result.title;
}
```

**Other question** is what would happen if I don't want to use tableview dequeue system ?

Comment: `return myCustomCell` seems like it would generate a static analyzer error because it should either be `_myCustomCell` or `self.myCustomCell`.   That said, what reason is there to save the cellview in this VC? You just want a convenient pointer to that cell?

Comment: @stevesliva it's self.myCustomCell sorry.

Comment: @stevesliva I didn't understand your question. But I just want to add some values to cell like a property. So, another method I called cell like this self.myCustomCell.titleLabel.text = .... etc.

Comment: It's concerning that you don't access the view through the view hierarchy mostly because of how UITableView manages cellviews behind the scenes.  Saving the cellview in a strong property at one point in time doesn't ensure it's always the cellview you want at indexPath 0,2.   Calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is really what you ought to do.  Even if you were to save it in a weak property, I don't think nil-checking it necessarily guarantees it's still the cell displayed at indexPath 0,2.  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and a typecast might be longwinded, but they're not heavyweight.

Comment: @stevesliva aww still doesn't work!

Comment: Is there another suggestion?